# Máscara input não funciona em campos dinâmicos

Tags: jquery

Estou usando a biblioteca `mask` para formatar valores, porcentagens e etc. Tenho um campo `carga_imposto` (tipo %), e outro `carga_valor` (tipo 0.00), os quais podem ser adicionados dinamicamente através do `jquery`. Para adicionar, funciona perfeitamente, porém, a máscara só funciona com os itens previamente carregados.

Ao criar um novo item, o `input` não é formatado.

HTML dos campos:

```
<div id="box_carga"  class="box_carga">
    <div class="row form-group">

        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
            <input type="text" id="carga_valor" name="carga_valor[]" placeholder="Valor" class="form-control valor" value="">
        </div> 

        <div class="col-12 col-md-1">
            <input type="text" id="carga_imposto" name="carga_imposto[]" placeholder="Imposto" class="form-control percentual" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="adicionar_carga"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML a ser clonado:

```
<div id="box_carga_clone" style="margin-top: 15px;" class="box_carga_clone hide">
    <div class="row form-group">

        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
            <input type="text" id="carga_valor" name="carga_valor[]" placeholder="Valor" class="form-control valor" value="">
        </div> 

        <div class="col-12 col-md-1">
            <input type="text" id="carga_imposto" name="carga_imposto[]" placeholder="Imposto" class="form-control percentual" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remover_carga"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery

Ao criar o campo dinamicamente, tentei adicionar `$('.carga_imposto').mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});`, mas sem sucesso:

```
$('.adicionar_carga').click(function(){
    $clone = $('.box_carga_clone.hide').clone(true);
    $clone.removeClass('hide');
    $('.box_carga').append($clone);
    $('.carga_imposto').mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});
});

$('.remover_carga').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
});       

$('.remover_carga_ativo').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Atualmente o resultado que eu tenho é:

O primeiro foi carregado em tela, o segundo foi adicionado dinamicamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi. Então, experimentei fazer a troca. Mas não deu certo.

Comment: Experimenta trocar `$('.carga_imposto').mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});` por `$clone.find('.carga_imposto').mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});`. Nos seus elementos clonados, tem que trocar o `id` por classe.

Comment: carga_imposto está como id nos elementos, deveria ser uma classe.

Comment: concordo, mas inclui a class, mas não dá certo... tecnicamente, deveria sim funcionar.

Comment: Não, o sistema aplica qualquer coisa no primeiro `id` que achar, não aplica em todos que tenham o mesmo `id`.

Comment: Sim, se for por class, deveria aplicar em uma próxima class, independente, mas, se ela estiver em tela... porém, se eu adicionar um novo elemento em tela, eu preciso dizer pra ele que ele precisa incluir também nesse elemento, e ai está o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Fala Sr. André, blz? Vamos por partes...seu código tem alguns pontos que podemos melhorar:

1. Você está utilizando IDs repetidos no mesmo documento, então realmente você terá problemas na manipulação destes. Veja `id="carga_valor"` e `id="carga_imposto"`;
2. Como você está criando mais elementos dinamicamente, é mais saudável você substituir por classes (para este caso);
3. Apesar dos elementos serem dinâmicos, você está clonando de um outro conjunto de elementos. Deixe os inputs que necessitam de máscara já inicializados no início do seu código, porque eles já existem e serão clonados com as devidas formatações;
4. Você incluiu um elemento `<button>` dentro de uma tag `<a>`. Tem algum motivo específico? Isso não está muito correto ;) .

Veja o exemplo funcional: https://codepen.io/tiagosabadini/pen/RwaRjJB?editors=1010